# Matching lowercase letter bounded by exactly three uppercase letters

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to find all instances of a lowercase character that is surrounded by exactly three upper case characters on each side. Then I want to print each occurrence of this pattern. This is a challenge in the python challenge. Here is what I have:

```
contents = "XXXiXXXjXXX"
contents.scan(/[^A-Z]*[A-Z]{3}[a-z][A-Z]{3}[^A-Z]*/) { |i| print i[3] }
```

It only prints `"i"`, when it should print `"ij"`. What is wrong with my regex?

Comment: Have you seen the result of `scan` without the block? It is `XXXiXXXj`. So `print i[3]` will only print one char.

Comment: then how do i repeatedly check for the pattern and extract each char?

Comment: This may be moot, if you end up drastically rewriting this, but have you tried testing this with more than three capital letters?  I expect your regex will match on `FOURxMORE`, finding occurrences of `[^A-Z]*` (i.e., _zero_ occurrences of `[^A-Z]`) between `F` and `O`, and between `R` and `E`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong, and it is not practical to explain what is wrong.

If you do not need to do it with a single regex, here is a straightforward way:

```
puts " #{contents} ".split(/[A-Z]{3}/).&(("a".."z").to_a).join
```

Answer (score 0):

2 things.

- Your `[^A-Z]*` doesn't do anything
- The scan pointer advances past the full match the first time which
  is why it won't pick up 'j'.

A somewhat complicated lookaround solution:

```
re = /
  (?<=[A-Z]{3}) # 3 uppers behind
  (?<![A-Z]{4}) # but not 4
  [a-z] # one lower
  (?=[A-Z]{3}) # 3 uppers ahead
  (?![A-Z]{4}) # but not 4
/x

'XXXiXXXjXXX'.scan re
#=> ["i", "j"]
```

Answer (score -1):

If you drop the pre/post criteria causing it not to match, the regex works.  Then you should add parens as a capture group around the value you want to extract, like this:

```
match = contents.match(/[A-Z]{3}([a-z])[A-Z]{3}/)
match[1] if match
```

Comment: how do i check for the pattern through the whole text, not just one match?

Comment: This will incorrectly match when it is preceded or followed by more than three capital letters.